# Get the newest data but only one

Tags: mysql

this is the table(followup) :

[image]

My question is, I wanted to select the newest data by `fol_date` for each `cust_name` inserted. The sample result I've marked with the red arrows. Anyone help?

Comment: note: table name -> followup

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Other answerers post their solutions but they failed to mention this is just a common problem of [tag:greatest-n-per-group], which has already well tested and highly [optimized solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8748986/684229). Personally I prefer the [left join solution of Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/684229) (the [original post with lots of other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/123481/684229)). In case you need last `n` records it is more complicated, but also [optimized and tested solutions exist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17001909/684229). Also see the tag [ta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   a.fol_date =
        (
            SELECT  MAX(fol_date)
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   b.cust_name = b.cust_name
        )
```

or by using `JOIN`,

The idea of the subquery is to get the latest `fol_date` for every `cust_name`. This will already give you the result you want but if you want to get the whole column within the row, you need to join it to the table itself provided that it match on two conditions, `cust_name` and `fol_date`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  cust_name, MAX(fol_date) fol_date
            FROM    tableName 
            GROUP   BY cust_name 
        ) b ON  a.cust_name = b.cust_name AND
                a.fol_date = b.fol_date
```

Comment: it's work but actually,

`SELECT  cust_name, MAX(fol_date) fol_date
            FROM    tableName 
            GROUP   BY cust_name`

That's the path of your answer that actually work as well, and same as @Edper said. So I don't need to using `inner join`, Thanks

Comment: If you only want the cust_name and max fol_date then the answer you accepted is fine, but most of the time you need other columns (such as the fol_id in your example data) in which case you need to use the solution posted here.

Comment: The fact now is, @JW's answer the better.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT cust_name, MAX(fol_date) as LatestDate
FROM FollowUp 
GROUP BY cust_name
```