# mysql Why variable is not changing in if

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query and IF clause. If it is false, @cid changes to category_id and @a must change to 1. The row below the highlighted one has to have @a again 1.

[image: @a is not changing]

Why does @a stay unchanged while @cid is changing ?

**code**

```
SET @a:=0;
SET @cid:=0;
SELECT @a, @cid, q.* FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY category_id
) AS q
WHERE IF(@cid=q.category_id, @a:=@a+1, (@a:=1) AND (@cid:=q.category_id))
```

**desired goal**

with each new category_id - @a has to start from 1 again and again

**the point of all of this**

i have a gallery with photos. almost every photo has a category

so i have a gallery categories page, where you can see all categories and 4 photos from each of it

so basically i need limit 4 from each category

**possible solution**

i can simply make a select of all category ids, then foreach

```
select * from photos where category_id = 1 LIMIT 4
select * from photos where category_id = 2 LIMIT 4
...
```

and union, but i kinda dont like 20+ selects

**so i tried the way when i count photo and take only 4 of them with nested select**

full query

```
SET @a:=0;
SET @cid:=0;
SELECT @a, @cid, q.* FROM (
    SELECT
    c.id AS cid,
    c.title AS category_title,
    c.slug AS category_slug,
    i.id AS image_id,
    i.title AS image_title,
    i.slug AS image_slug,
    i.place AS image_place,
    i.created_at AS image_date
    FROM categories AS c
    JOIN photos AS i 
    ON c.id = i.category_id
    WHERE c.visible AND i.visible
    GROUP BY i.id
    HAVING COUNT(i.id) > 0
    ORDER BY c.priority, c.title, i.priority, i.title
) AS q
WHERE IF(@cid=q.cid, @a:=@a+1, (@a:=1) AND (@cid:=q.cid))
AND @a <= 4
```

**BUT** - it does not set @a to 1 as in simplified version above

---

**STUPID BUT WORKING SOLUTION TO EXAMPLES (3-rd leg)**

when i add to select 1 AS one
and change @a:=q.one - **IT WORKS**
but it is odd

**stupid working code**

```
SET @a:=0;
SET @cid:=0;
SELECT @a, @cid, q.* FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS ONE
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY category_id
) AS q
WHERE IF(@cid=q.category_id, @a:=@a+1, (@a:=q.one) AND (@cid:=q.category_id))
```

---

SO the main question - **WHY DOES NOT @a:=1 WORK and @a:=q.one DOES WORK ?**

Comment: Code, not screenshots please

Comment: flag -1 for WHAT ? really im starting to hate this community. last place for help. code added

Comment: What is the desired outcome you're looking for?

Comment: The @a with each new category_id has to start from 1 again and again - the desired goal

Comment: Ive added the whole story and STUPID solution. Can you tell me WHY @a:=1 does not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT rn, id, category_id, title
  FROM
(
  SELECT *, @a := IF(@c = category_id, @a + 1, 1) rn, @c := category_id
    FROM photos CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c := NULL, @a := 0) i
   ORDER BY category_id
) q
 WHERE rn <= 4;
```

Output:

```
| RN | ID | CATEGORY_ID |  TITLE |
|----|----|-------------|--------|
|  1 | 43 |           1 | Title1 |
|  1 | 28 |           2 | Title2 |
|  2 | 42 |           2 | Title3 |
|  1 | 11 |           3 | Title4 |
|  1 |  3 |           4 | Title5 |
|  2 | 29 |           4 | Title6 |
|  3 | 33 |           4 | Title7 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b99b35/8)** demo

---

Here is a fix for your code to produce the correct row numbers

```
SET @a:=0;
SET @cid:=0;   
SELECT @a, @cid, q.*, @cid:=q.category_id FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM photos
    ORDER BY category_id
) AS q
WHERE @a := IF(@cid=q.category_id, @a+1, 1)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b99b35/12)** demo

*The order of SQL statement execution does matter.*

Comment: my example is a simplified version of what i want - i just dont get WHY is does not work. ill add the whole gole to the question and one stupid, but working solution

Comment: whole story and solution added

Comment: It's not working because your variables are evaluated at the wrong time. You should have the category_id's value of the previous row in the @cid. But you have the current row's value. Take a closer look at this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b99b35/6 with my query.

Comment: Now using an inline view (an inner select) in your case is total waste of resources. There is no reason to materialize the whole recordset before you start calculating row numbers. You can and should do it right in the inner select. Then in the outer select you can filter out records based on row numbers.

Comment: no, they are okay. @cid is updated with category_id, but @a does not update to 1. see the my working stupid example - @a is updated with q.one (which is 1), but does not update with simple 1. why?

Comment: and what you are suggesting is LIMIT 4 in each select (but mysql cant do inner limit) - i can simply take all category id`s -> make lots of selects with LIMIT and then UNION the results.
Ill try IF in inner select, but i dont get, why @a doesnt reset to 1..

Comment: There are only the inner select (to populate row numbers) and the outer select to filter out unnecessary rows based on row numbers. *...what you are suggesting is LIMIT 4 in each select...*. What other (*each*) selects are you referring to???

Comment: inner Limit 4 for every category would be a solution, but there is not inner limit in mysql. So i have to manually count the rows and cut unnecessary. I understand, you are suggesting to count the rows in inner select - but i still take all rows with inner select, just count them there, not in outer select -> what is the difference ?

Comment: The difference is you're inflicting an unnecessary step. In order for your query to work (to select only top 4 for each category) you'll have to introduce another outer select (third) with where clause or use a having clause. Again 'The order of SQL statement execution does matter.' SELECT is evaluated after WHERE.

Comment: Thank you, Ive moved IF and row count to inner select as you suggested. The only thing i dont get - why @a:=1 didnt work while the @cid changed.